# No "R.xxx" files generated

Tags: android, fragment

An Android project I imported does not have the gen folder. I manually created it. I cleaned the project, closed and reopened it but still no "R.xxx" was generated under this gen folder.

In the meantime, inside my src/*.java files, all the "R.xxx" fields could not be resolved due to them not existing; e.g.

```
setContentView(R.layout.tutlist_fragment);
```

Gives me this error: "tutlist_fragment cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: try to clean your project, it will trigger eclipse builder to generate  the R class

Comment: I would suggest, have a brand new project created through -->New Project--->Android--> and physically copy your files to corresponding folders and refresh the project. It seems something messedup with your project structure.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to check all XML files for errors. I've experienced this same issue several times, and when cleaning the project doesn't help, it's always been an XML issue. Eclipse (if you're using it) might not catch bad references and other little things in your XML, and that can cause R.java to fail to generate.

Comment: exactly. R.XXX files are generated from the xml files and if there is an error in the xml files, there will be no R.xx files and you would not be able to reference them in you activities.

Comment: Thank you very much, mikedenny. It is working now. I deleted the gen folder again (thought just to try it again to see what happens), closed and reopened the project and the "R.xxx" file got generated.

I am all set. Thanks.